# in UVM RAL, a reg defined as no reset value, but set/update a '0' data on it won't trigger bus transaction

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

In `ral` file, I have something like:

```
class ral_reg_AAA_0 extends uvm_reg;
rand uvm_reg_field R2Y;

constraint R2Y_default {
}

function new(string name = "AAA_0");
    super.new(name, 32,build_coverage(UVM_NO_COVERAGE));
endfunction: new
virtual function void build();
  this.R2Y = uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("R2Y",,get_full_name());
  this.R2Y.configure(this, 12, 4, "RW", 0, 12'h0, 0, 1, 1);
endfunction: build

`uvm_object_utils(ral_reg_AAA_0)

endclass : ral_reg_AAA_0
```

You can find `R2Y` is set to `has_reset = 0`, in real RTL, it's `'X'` value by default
but if I use set/update mechanism to write this reg, if `write data is 0`, which is equal to reset value in R2Y (even `has_reset = 0`), seems like RAL will treat `m_mirror == m_desired` so there won't be a bus transaction for this reg access.

```
like
env.regmodel.AAA_0.R2Y.set(0);
env.regmodel.AAA_0.update(status,UVM_FRONTDOOR);
```

Does that make sense? I thought no matter which value I set to these kind of regs, there should be always bus transaction happening.

PS: mirrored and desired values are 2-state vectors, and even reg fields are set as 'no reset' value, m_mirrored initial value for a reg field is still 0. if RTL reset value is "x", for instance, there are 10 regs in design, I want to randomly pick up any number of them to write them with random value (of course, 0 is also a legal value), seems I will miss those '0' value register setting in this case.
I am using a workaround for now, flush all regs to be 0 value with a 'write' ral method, it can meet my expectation with some extra overhead on bus

Answer (score 0):

The internal representations of the mirrored and desired values are 2-state vectors and are stored on a per field basis. This means that when created, your `R2Y` field's mirrored value is 0. By setting the desired value to 0, the values are still the same, which is why no bus transaction is started. If you want to force a bus transaction, just use the `write(...)` method:

```
env.regmodel.AAA_0.write(status, 0);  // this will write the value '0' to the register
```

If you still want to use `set(...)` to play with the register fields, then you could try something like:

```
env.regmodel.AAA_0.R2Y.set(0);
env.regmodel.AAA_0.write(status, env.regmodel.AAA_0.get());
```

Comment: thanks for reply, yup, a direct write always work, but it's not convenient to directly call a 'write' in my case.
I want to leverage RAL block randomize() to do register random program, like I use reg.set(value) to update some desired value for some regs, then I don't need to care which regs need to be updated, just simply call 

reg_block.get_registers(regs);
  if(regs.size() !=0) begin
    foreach (regs[i]) begin
      regs[i].update(status,UVM_FRONTDOOR);
    end
  end

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer. I wrote `update(...) instead of write(...) so look at it again.

Comment: This is exactly why I wrote the second code snippet. You can just apply `reg.get()` returns the desired value (the one that gets changed by the call to `randomize()`. You just plug that into `write()` and it does what you want.